# PayPal's tracking id

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-nvp

Sometimes PayPal breaks, and it doesn't return a tracking_id.  At the same time, it completes the payment on it's own servers.  This is a problem for me, because even thought the payment was successful, my server ends up with a blank tracking_id column in the database table, which causes me lots of issues

If this were to happen again, will the following if statement be enough to capture such an event?

```
if( !isset($trackingId) || empty($trackingId) || $trackingId == null || $trackingId == "" ) {

    // something is wrong

} else {

    // continue as normal

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [empty](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php).

> Determine whether a variable is considered to be empty. A variable is
>   considered empty if it does not exist or if its value equals FALSE.
>   empty() does not generate a warning if the variable does not exist.
>
> The following things are considered to be empty:
>
> ```
> "" (an empty string) 
> 0 (0 as an integer)
> 0.0 (0 as a float) 
> "0" (0 as a string) 
> NULL 
> FALSE 
> array() (an empty array) 
> $var; (a variable declared, but without a value)
> ```